# Android SQLite Database and return a column

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

so I have an SQLite Database that has columns stop_number, stop_lat, and stop_lon. I can't find a coherent answer as to how to search a stop number and return the corresponding stop_lat and stop_lon? I've tried several variations of query commands but I can't seem to get it just right. Any help for someone new to data basing?

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Comment: And where is your table name?

Comment: Things along the line of database.rawquery("STOPS","stop_number","status = ?",null,null,null,null); I'm really clueless even a good refrence to learn database query would be nice, everything I find just kind of jumps you in cold water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(   TABLE_STOP,
                            new String[] { KEY_STOP_LAT, KEY_STOP_LONG },
                            KEY_STOP_NUMBER + "=?",
                            new String[] { <your stop number as string> },
                            null,
                            null,
                            null);

if(cursor.getCount()>0){

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    float stop_lat = cursor.getFloat(0); // first column requested in the second query argument
    float stop_long = cursor.getFloat(1); // second column requested in the second query argument
}

cursor.close();
```

Doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Answer (score 0):

try to run this query. I worked in my case.

```
        DataBaseHelper databaseManager = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        databaseManager.openDataBase();
       SQLiteDatabase   db = databaseManager.getWritableDatabase();
        uCursor = db.rawQuery("select distinct stop_number from tablename", null);
        if(uCursor != null && uCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (uCursor.moveToNext()) {
                String stop_number = uCursor.getString(uCursor.getColumnIndex("stop_number"));
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select distinct stop_lang, stop_lat from table where stop_number = "+stop_number, null);
                if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String stop_lang = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("stop_lang"));
                        String stop_lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("stop_lat"));

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```